# Error: Cannot find module 'zeparser'

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I have node.js successfully installed. I have created the file

```
var http = require('http');
var url=require('url');
var fs=require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

fs.readFile('/var/www/nodeJS/client.html' ,
function ( err, data ) {
 if ( err ) {
  console.log( err );
  res.writeHead(500);
  return res.end( 'Error loading client.html' );
 }
 res.writeHead( 200 );
 res.end( data );
});

}).listen(8124, '127.0.0.1');

io.listen(http);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
});
```

The error occurs whenever I use the io object. Without io it works fine.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zeparser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodeJS/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/active-x-obfuscator/index.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

After this I have also separately installed module zeparser. My default npm installation directory seems to be /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

I have set NODE_PATH as

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```

but get the same error.

Then I tried to copy zeparser module to /var/www/nodeJS/node_modules. Then the error changes to

```
/var/www/nodeJS/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:104
  server.on('error', function(err) {
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
    at new Manager (/var/www/nodeJS/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:104:10)
    at Object.exports.listen (/var/www/nodeJS/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodeJS/app.js:35:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:903:3
```

Comment: folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules is for global modules only. if you have installed them locally then run it from the project folder.

Answer (score 5):

On your root project, do:

```
$ sudo npm install zeparser
```

It resolved the problem for me.